# How to fetch image from Mongodb and display using React JS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, backend, mern

Image is getting stored in the form of binary image but not able to fetch and display it in the web page using React JS

index.js (backend)

```
import express from "express"
import cors from "cors"
import mongoose from "mongoose"
import multer from "multer"


const app = express()
app.use(express.json())
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

mongoose.set("strictQuery", false)
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/prj1", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
}, () => {
    console.log("Connected !")
})
const TherSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    spec: String,
    experience: String,
    qualification: String,
    photo: {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String
    }

})

const Therapist1 = new mongoose.model("Therapist1", TherSchema)

const upload = multer();

//adding therapist data in mongodb
app.post('/therapist', upload.single('photo'), (req, res) => {
    const { name, spec, experience, qualification } = req.body;
    const therapist = new Therapist1({
        name: name,
        spec: spec,
        experience: experience,
        qualification: qualification,
        photo: {
            data: req.file.buffer,
            contentType: req.file.mimetype
        }
    });
    therapist.save(err => {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.send({ message: 'Therapist added!' });
        }
    });
});

//fetching data from mongodb
app.get("/chattherapdisplay", (req, res) => {
    Therapist1.find((err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        } else {
            res.status(200).send(data);
        }
    });
});



app.listen(9000, () => {
    console.log("Started at port 9000")
})
```

chattherapist.js (frontend)

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import "./customer.css"
import axios from "axios"

const ChatTherapistdisplay = () => {


    const [therapist, setTherapist] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  const fetchdata = async () => {
    const data = await axios.get("http://localhost:9000/chattherapdisplay");
    setTherapist(data.data);
  };
  fetchdata();
}, []);

return (
  <div className="maincrd">
    {therapist.map((therapist) => (
      <div className="crd1" key={therapist._id}>
        Name: {therapist.name} <br />
        Specialization: {therapist.spec} <br />
        Qualification: {therapist.qualification} <br />
        Experience: {therapist.experience} <br />
        Photo:
        {therapist.photo && (
          <img
            src={`data:${therapist.photo.contentType};base64,${btoa(
              new Uint8Array(therapist.photo.data).reduce(
                (data, byte) => data + String.fromCharCode(byte),
                ''
              )
            )}`}
            alt="therapist"
          />
        )}
        <br />
        <div className="bkapp">
          <a href="#">Book Appointment</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    ))}
  </div>
);



}

export default ChatTherapistdisplay
```

Able to fetch all the attributes like name, experience, etc. but the image is not visible.
How to display the image which stored in form of binary

Comment: just curious, why do you store image buffer to database rather then store only the path image?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).